# Find contours of function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

Is it possible to get a data frame of the ..level.. value when I use stat_density2d?

Suppose I have a data frame df which has three columns called 'x', 'y' and 'f'. f=f(x,y) is supposed to be the value of a function at x,y.

```
ggplot(data=f, aes(x=x,y=y,z=f)) + stat_density2d(aes(color = ..level..))
```

will plot the contour map of this function. I would like to access the ..level.. data frame (whatever it is) so that I can select out for contours where the value of the function is above a certain threshold.

Comment: there will be a data frame for each layer in `ggplot_build(.)$data`

Comment: thanks! i just stumbled into ggplot_build() as soon as I posted the question. do you know if there is a more direct way to get the contours of a function?

Comment: what about `?contourLines`

Comment: `ggplot2:::contour_lines` might help

Comment: thank you @rawr @Khashaa! don't know why i didn't find that.